# Spring Reactor: Context for each flux element

Tags: java, asynchronous, project-reactor

I have a pull based stream data source (just like Kafka). And I'd like to apply the reactor on this event processing application.

Currently, I created an infinite sequence of events using EmitterProcessor. And it is subscribed at initial time once and never canceled.

The following code indicates what I've done.

```
public void initialize(){
    EmitterProcessor<Event> emitter = ...
    emitter.flatmap(this::step1)
           .flatmap(this::step2)
           .flatmap(this::finalStep)
         //.subscriberContext(...)
           .subscribe()
}
```

For each event in the initial `Flux<Event>`, I need to maintain/update a context so that I can get all inputs and results for each step and do some reporting in the final step.

Passing the immutable `Context` class from step to step is an option but this will cause all `step()` have an additional parameter. And not all `step()` will use the `Context`. In that case it seems ugly you just pass `Context` and return `Pair<Context,OtherResult>`. The `Pair` is ugly as well.

So I prefer something like `ThreadLocal<Context>`. Obviously in reactor the replacement is `subscriberContext()`. However according my code, the `initialize()` will be invoked once. The `Flux<Event>` will be `subscribe()` once. The `subscriberContext` is not at my `Event` level but subscription level. So there will be only a single context in my code. It not works.

The question is should I regard the event stream a `Flux<Event>` or multiple `Mono<Event>` and make subscription on each event? If `Mono<Event>` is the best practice, then I can directly use `subscriberContext()`. But is there any assemble time overhead (assemble on every event coming)?

In [reactor-kafka](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-kafka/blob/master/reactor-kafka-samples/src/main/java/reactor/kafka/samples/SampleConsumer.java), it makes each batch of `Record` a `Flux<Record>`, how can it implements something like record level context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how late you last need the information in this context, you might have the option of using a single `flatMap` to create a scope for each event and assign them their own context:

```
public void initialize(){
    EmitterProcessor<Event> emitter = ...
    emitter.flatMap(eventForScope ->
        Mono.just(eventForScope)
            .flatmap(this::step1)
            .flatmap(this::step2)
            .flatmap(this::finalStep)
            .subscriberContext(...) //context for ONE event
        )
        .subscribe()
}
```

This can be tuned, some late steps might not need the per-event context anymore so you can move these outside the outer `flatMap`, etc...

This works because the inside of a `flatMap` can see the "main" `Context`, but changes to the inside context aren't visible to the outside / main sequence.

Comment: Doesn’t your solution too instantiate a new `Mono` on each event? And doesn’t this mean an overhead of assembly on each event? Since, if so, the definitely ugly `Pair` approach might arguably be faster. Or, am I totally wrong with this assumption? But your hint how to tune this goes into the same direction.

Comment: it does, so the "pair" solution could have less overhead, but leaks into the `stepX` method signatures

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually, I am also a fan of your solution since it is just clean. However, I've spend the last days on reading about the JIT. It seems like your solution shouldn’t have any overhead at all, since apparently object that do not escape the method scope are not necessarily instantiated at all https://www.bettercodebytes.com/the-cost-of-object-creation-in-java-including-garbage-collection/ .